# Compactness with the Zariski topology

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces, zariski-topology

While solving:

> Prove $\mathbb{R}$ with the Zariski topology is compact

it seems like the Zariski topology should make a compact space with whatever set it is definied on:

To solve this case, I took a cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $\mathbb{R}$, and a $U_1 \in \mathcal{U}$ which is inherently open, so $\mathbb{R}\smallsetminus U_1 $ is closed, and by the Zariski topology this is finite. We then pcik points out of $\mathbb{R} \smallsetminus U_1$ and find a set in $\mathcal{U}$ which covers that point. Since there are finite points, there are finite sets to cover them, so a subcover made of $U_1$ and this finite number of subsets is also finite, i.e. compact.

But this method seems independent of being in $\mathbb{R}$. In any finite set with the Zariski topology, any cover will have an obvious finite subcover? In the infinte case, the above argument should still hold?

So, is any set with the Zariski topology compact?

Comment: Your proof that $\mathbb R$ is compact with respect to the Zariski topology is correct. But I do not understand your last question. The Zariski topology is not defined for any set.

Comment: Let me just start by making a remark; there is no notion of 'Zariski' topology on any set. There is however a notion of 'cofinite topology' on any set, in which the open sets are sets with finite complement. It is true that a set with the cofinite topology is compact (exercise).

Comment: @user45878 Thanks, so is the method for any set the same as mine given for $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Zariski topology on $F^n$, for $F$ a field, the closed sets are the zeros of polynomials in $n$ indeterminates.

In the case $n=1$, these sets are finite, except for the whole set. So the Zariski topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is the cofinite topology, which is compact.

The Zariski topology is likewise compact on $F^n$, because the space is Noetherian anyway.

It's unclear what you mean with “any set with the Zariski topology”.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks, it seems the definition I had of the Zariski topology was incomplete and that I meant the cofinite topology. By "any set with the Zariski topology" I meant the space of a set X with the Zariski topolgy, but with this definition it no longer makes sense